# Optimized build for AMD Piledriver arch-Unreal Engine 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compiler-optimization, avx, amd-processor

To begin with, in order to use Unreal Engine 4 you have to build it using Visual Studio 2013.In other words, you are able to optimize compiler settings in order to optimize overall performance.

However, I am a little bit newbie when it come down to programming. So I need your help, what I should do enhance programs performance?

I was able to find in VS2013 how I could enable /arch:avx instruction sets. However, my CPU  also supports XOP and FMA3 and FM4. How can I enable them?

Comment: Visual Studio is not the best compiler for auto-targeting for a particular processor. It will not generate FMA instructions by itself unless you specify AVX2 (which Piledriver does not have). Furthermore,   no current AMD processors efficiently handle 256-bit AVX. The best you can do is specify `/arch:AVX` and let it use VEX-encoded 128-bit auto-vectorization.

Comment: Is there any other option I can enable in order to increase performance?